# Using pandas in Lambda to align data from a csv file and sending it out to email

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

I'm having problem with aligning the data using pandas. Below is the snippet of my code:

```
    s3_client.upload_file(csv_file_path, s3_bucket, s3_key)

    object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key)
    
    df = pd.read_csv(object['Body'])
    df.index = df.index + 1

    selected_columns = df[['InstanceId','Platform', 'State', 'ImageName', 'ImageId']]
    tabulated_data = selected_columns.to_string(index=True, header=True, justify='left')
    
    print(tabulated_data)               

    # Send out email through SNS
    subject = 'ALERT | EC2 Instances with INTL AMI'
    message = f"blablabla \n{tabulated_data}"
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn=sns_topic_arn,
        Message=message,
        Subject=subject,
        MessageStructure='string',
    )
```

Below is what I got from email pov:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPNwP.png)

I have tried using HTML but SNS does not support HTML. I have also tried using max_colwidth but it doesn't seems to make any changes.

Restrictions: I am not able to use prettytable or tabulate modules because we don't have that modules in our available Lambda layers.

I'm expecting to have data tabulated in such format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTGhZ.png)